# How do I dynamically add TypeOrm configurations from a secrets store when generating migrations?

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

I'm trying to set up a postgres connection with TypeOrm that dynamically pulls configurations from a secrets source (asynchronously) and generates a new migration.

I've attempted to use async await to asynchronously set both environment and local variables that will be used by the postgres.config.ts file when the typeorm-cli runs, but i continually get errors.

```
// src/config/defaults/postgres.config.ts

const postgresConfig = (async () => {
  try {
    const db: PostgresConfig = await secretsSource.getSecret();

    return {
        type: 'postgres',
        host: db.host,
        port: db.port,
        username: db.username,
        password: db.password,
        database: db.database,
        entities: [path.join(__dirname, '../**/*.entity{.ts,.js}')],
        migrationsRun: true,
        logging: true,
        logger: 'file',
        migrations: [path.join(__dirname, '../migrations/**/*{.ts,.js}')],
        cli: {
          migrationsDir: 'src/migrations',
        },
    } as ConnectionOptions;
  } catch (error) {
      // ... handle error
  }
})();

export default postgresConfig;

// package.json

{
    scripts: {
        "typeorm": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js --config src/config/defaults/postgres.config.ts",
        "typeorm:migrate": "npm run typeorm migration:generate -- -n",
        "typeorm:run": "npm run typeorm migration:run"
    }
};
```

I expect that when running "npm run typeorm:migrate initial", the script will point back to the config file run the file asynchronously, wait for the code to provide the necessary DB configurations, and generate migrations, but it seems that the script doesn't run any of the code as expected and I continually get the following error:

Error during migration generation:
{ MissingDriverError: Wrong driver: "undefined" given. Supported drivers are: ..... }

I need dynamically fetch db configurations because I have different environments that require different configurations.